# replacing specific key-values (with foreach) in an array stops further execution of PHP-script. How to solve?

Tags: php, foreach

I am struggling to get a small PHP script to work properly.

The related script is working properly. The only additional thing I want to do is in the column "werkgebied" to replace the numbers with corresponding text values (like 1 = Nederland, 5 = Friesland, and so on.

To achieve that, I have been using the following code

```
foreach ($result as $key=>$val) 
{
    if ($key='pf_werkgebied' && $val=1) 
    {
        $val="Nederland";
    }
}
echo $val;
echo '<br>';

foreach ($result as $key=>$val) 
{
    if ($key='pf_werkgebied' && $val=5) 
    {
        $val = "Friesland";
    }
}
echo $val;
echo '<br>';
```

The full script is displayed below:

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ");
$output = '';


if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
 $search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
 $query = "
 SELECT * FROM phpbb_profile_fields_data
 INNER JOIN phpbb_users ON
 phpbb_profile_fields_data.user_id=phpbb_users.user_id
 WHERE pf_voornaam COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR pf_achternaam COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%".$search."%' 
 OR pf_woonplaats COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%".$search."%' 
 OR pf_telefoon_vast COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%".$search."%' 
 OR pf_telefoon_mobiel COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR user_email COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%".$search."%'
 OR pf_werkgebied COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%".$search."%'
 ";
}
else
{
 $query = "SELECT d.pf_voornaam, d.pf_achternaam, d.pf_werkgebied,
 d.pf_ei_opl_afgerond, CASE WHEN d.pf_ei_opl_afgerond = 1 THEN 'voor 2000'
 WHEN d.pf_ei_opl_afgerond = 10 THEN '2007' 
 WHEN d.pf_ei_opl_afgerond = 12 THEN '2009' 
 WHEN d.pf_ei_opl_afgerond = 15 THEN '2012' 
 WHEN d.pf_ei_opl_afgerond = 17 THEN '2014' 
 WHEN d.pf_ei_opl_afgerond = 18 THEN '2015' 
 WHEN d.pf_ei_opl_afgerond = 20 THEN '2017' 
 END AS fly
 FROM phpbb_profile_fields_data d
 ORDER BY d.pf_achternaam ASC";
}
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

foreach ($result as $key=>$val) 
{
     if ($key='pf_werkgebied' && $val=1) 
    {
        $val="Nederland";
    }
}
echo $val;
echo '<br>';

foreach ($result as $key=>$val) 
{
    if ($key='pf_werkgebied' && $val=5) 
    {
        $val = "Friesland";
    }
}
echo $val;
echo '<br>';


if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $output .= '
  <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table bordered">
    <tr>
     <th>Voornaam</th>
     <th>Achternaam</th>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>Afgestudeerd</th>
     <th>Werkgebied</th>
    </tr>
 ';

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $output .= '
   <tr>
    <td>'.$row["pf_voornaam"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["pf_achternaam"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["user_email"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["fly"].'</td>
<td>'.$row["pf_werkgebied"].'</td>
   </tr>
  ';
 }
 echo $output;
}
else
{
 echo 'Data Not Found';
}

?>
```

What is going wrong here? What should be improved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the valuable feedback I have received here, I have been able to write a script that has solved the issue of converting numbers in a multidimensional array into corresponding values.

It is a matter of the following steps:
1: exploding the several field values of an array element
2: processing the individual elements
3: imploding the processed individual elements back into an array element.

The result can be seen [via this link.](http://www.tukhut.nl/test5/fetch18.php)

Please find below the script that did the trick

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "XXX", "YYY", "ZZZ");
$output = '';

if(isset($_POST["query"]))
{
$search = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["query"]);
$query = "
SELECT * FROM phpbb_profile_fields_data
INNER JOIN phpbb_users 
ON phpbb_profile_fields_data.user_id=phpbb_users.user_id
WHERE pf_voornaam COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%".$search."%'
OR pf_achternaam COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%".$search."%' 
OR pf_woonplaats COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%".$search."%' 
OR pf_telefoon_vast COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%".$search."%' 
OR pf_telefoon_mobiel COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%".$search."%'
OR user_email COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%".$search."%'
OR pf_werkgebied COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI LIKE '%".$search."%'
";
}
else
{
$query = "SELECT d.pf_voornaam, d.pf_achternaam, d.pf_werkgebied,
d.pf_ei_opl_afgerond, CASE WHEN d.pf_ei_opl_afgerond = 1 THEN 'voor 2000' 
WHEN d.pf_ei_opl_afgerond = 10 THEN '2007' 
WHEN d.pf_ei_opl_afgerond = 12 THEN '2009' 
WHEN d.pf_ei_opl_afgerond = 15 THEN '2012' 
WHEN d.pf_ei_opl_afgerond = 17 THEN '2014' 
WHEN d.pf_ei_opl_afgerond = 18 THEN '2015' 
WHEN d.pf_ei_opl_afgerond = 20 THEN '2017' 
END AS fly
FROM phpbb_profile_fields_data d
ORDER BY d.pf_achternaam ASC";
}

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
 <th>Voornaam</th>
 <th>Achternaam</th>
 <th>Email</th>
 <th>Afgestudeerd</th>
 <th>Werkgebied</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{


$selected_opts=explode(';',$row['pf_werkgebied']);
foreach ($selected_opts as & $selected_opt) 
{
if ($selected_opt == '1'){ $selected_opt = "Nederland"; }
elseif ($selected_opt == '5'){ $selected_opt = "Groningen"; }
elseif ($selected_opt == '6'){ $selected_opt = "Friesland"; }
elseif ($selected_opt == '7'){ $selected_opt = "Drenthe"; }
elseif ($selected_opt == '8'){ $selected_opt = "Gelderland"; }
elseif ($selected_opt == '9'){ $selected_opt = "Utrecht"; }
elseif ($selected_opt == '18'){ $selected_opt = "Brabant"; }
elseif ($selected_opt == '19'){ $selected_opt = "Limburg"; }

// echo "$selected_opt <br />";
}

$row['pf_werkgebied'] = implode(', ', $selected_opts);
// echo "$selected_opts_string <br />";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['pf_voornaam'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['pf_achternaam'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['user_email'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['fly'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['pf_werkgebied'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I recommend you to read more about OOP [here](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/web-beginner-en-bH5s3/0/1) is nice tutorial and MVC more [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/the-mvc-pattern-and-php-1/). And of course use [SOLID](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design).
Because it's not good to use requests to database in the same script with output.
Next thing, try to minimize code, it means this:
     `$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
     foreach ($result as $key=>$val) 
     {
       if ($key='pf_werkgebied' && $val=1) 
       {
          $val="Nederland";
       } else if($key='pf_werkgebied' && $val=5){
          $val = "Friesland";
       } else {....}
 }
       echo $val;
       echo '<br>';`

etc.

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestions.
OOP, MVC and SOLID are on my to do list now.

I tried to minimize my code the way you have suggested, unfortunately that did not solve the issue.

Comment: Are you sure that `$row["pf_werkgebied"]` returns what you want, the string, not integer? Perhaps it return index of the row, but for your task you need the second element of array. Possibly you could get it with `$row["pf_werkgebied"][1]`. 
And it will be great if you'll show us your debug for request with `print_r`

Comment: hi Grynets, the result of print_r ($output); shows only the headers of the table (which are: Voornaam Achternaam Email Afgestudeerd Werkgebied)

Comment: My bad... I meant `print_r($row)`

Comment: If you check the link in the first line of my question, you will see the result of:
-- print_r($result)
-- then a white line
-- then the result of print_r($row)

Comment: And if you check: http://www.tukhut.nl/test5/fetch9.php 
you will see that print_r($row) shows an empty result ...

Comment: @PiotrLinski, as you can see everywhere you get `[pf_werkgebied] => [3]` not string. And in your code you use `<td>'.$row["pf_werkgebied"].'</td>'`  which get exactly which you receive - the number. 
But your `$row` have no connection with `$val` which you set as "Friesland" etc. This means that you have to make same convert for your `$row`. Like you did with `$val`. Smth like this: `if($row["pf_werkgebied"] == 1){ return "Friesland" }` and etc. for each your case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136397/discussion-between-piotr-linski-and-grynets).

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this, you don't need to write $key='pf_werkgebied' && $val=5 this if you have to compare  same "pf_werkgebied" with $key

```
$data = array(1=>'Nederland',5=>'Friesland'); //put name in array as you alreay know the names

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

foreach ($result as $resultdata) {

switch ($resultdata['pf_werkgebied']){ // using switch instead of if condition

    case "1" :
        $val = $data[1];
        echo $data[1];

    case "5" :
        $val = $data[5];
        echo $data[5];

  }

 }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. However, when using your suggestion, a bit further in the script:  if(mysqli_num_rows($resultdata) > 0) now triggers "Data not found". And no table results are displayed.

Comment: for mysqli_num_rows you need to use $result ( as it is the table data) itself instead of $resultdata , please try this

Comment: hi Sooraz, I did, now I get the "old" situation, which means: the echo's are displayed correctly and after that only the table heads are displayed, table content is not shown.